# Why can't we enable Apple Push Notifications on Delphi Seattle anymore?

Tags: delphi, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, delphi-10-seattle

When we head over the Entitlement List on `Delphi Seattle`, we can no longer enable the `PushNotifications` for `iOS` like in the old versions.

It states : "Android only."

[image]

Why?

Comment: This might be better to post at Embarcadero QualityPortal. 
https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Documentation for Delphi 10 Seattle states that iOS push notifications feature exists.    http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Remote_Notifications_%28iOS_and_Android%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the RAD Studio documentation topic "[Entitlement List](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Entitlement_List)":

> RAD Studio does not allow you to set any Entitlement for the current
>   iOS project from the IDE, although you can manually customize the
>   entitlements file.

So while it is possible to enable GCM support in an Android application and receive data from remote servers, Apple Push Notifications can not be enabled from this project options screen. (I am not working with RAD Studio so I can not describe the steps which are required to enable APN).